# c++ and injected base name

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces

The following code does not compile in gcc:

```
namespace One{
   class A{
   };
};

namespace Two{
   class A{
      public:
         void what(){
            cout << "Two::A says what!" << endl;
         }
   };

   class B : public One::A{
      public:
         B(){
            A xx;
            xx.what();
         }
   };

};
```

And it gives:

```
gccbug.cpp: In constructor ‘Two::B::B()’:
gccbug.cpp:23: error: ‘class One::A’ has no member named ‘what’
```

Now, I was told that this is correct behavior (due to injected base name of One::A making A refer to One::A). However, this code compiles in C# (well, after changing a few things), so this seems to be c++ specific.

What I'm wondering is.. why? Is there a specific purpose for injecting the base name "One::A" as "A"?

Comment: Just for reference, C# != C++.  I'm not sure why you're comparing the two

Comment: I can't say for sure (I don't have my copy with me right now), but as an aside, questions about why the C++ language was designed the way it was are often answered in a book called "The Design and Evolution of C++" by Stroustrup.

Comment: @TonyTheLion, Well, it's the other c-like programming language that has "namespace", and one which I had access to a compiler to. I'm not saying there's only "One True Way" in which this is correct, but this did not seem intuitive, at least given this example.

Comment: @Tony The Lion Isn't the fact that C# != C++ what makes it _worth_ comparing them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is that in C++ you are likely to refer to the base class name in the initializer list of the constructor, like this:

```
namespace Two {

  /*...*/

  class B : public One::A {
  public:
     B():A()
     {
        /*...*/
     }
   };
}
```

Of course the purpose then is different from the one in your example, because you actually declare a local variable inside the constructor, whereas in my example, the `A()` refers to the object of type `A` that is implicit in the definition of `class B` due to inheritance.

However, the situation of my example is more likely to occur, so I guess they thought let's not require the namespace to be made explicit in this case. As a consequence, any reference to `A` without a namespace is interpreted as referring to the base class, rather than any other class named `A`, even if it is in the same namespace as the declaration of `B`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense actually. Although I do say it feels a little like a "hack".

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a specific purpose for injecting the base name "One::A" as "A"?

Yes. It is so that you could write this:

```
namespace N
{
   class A
   {
       A *a;
   };
}
```

In the *absence* of injected-name, you've to write `N::A *a` which is not nice.

Note that it is because of injected-name, the following lines are allowed:

```
A::A *a1; //ok
A::A::A *a2; //ok 
A::A::A::A *a3; //ok 
A::A::A::A::A *a4; //ok 
//and so on
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/A6O2f)

Comment: Isn't this different from the situation explained by the asker? In the original example `class B` was inside one namespace, but the class it is derived from was in another.

Comment: @jogojapan But `class B` inherits all the names from its base class, including the injected name of the base class itself. Being in an inner scope, it hides names from the surrounding namespace.

Comment: @Bo Persson Yes. I am just pointing out that the above example does not quite illustrate this point. In the above example the only reference to `class A` is inside the same namespace as the declaration of the class itself. You don't need name injection for that.

Comment: @jogojapan: You need name injection for that too. Otherwise, why does `A::A::A::A *a` work?

Comment: Ok, granted. There is name injection _at work_ there. The key difference I see between what I thought the question was about and the example above is that the question demonstrates that the compiler _prefers_ `One::A` over `Two::A`, rather than merely pointing out the name clash. What is the motivation for that preference?

Comment: @jogojapan: After my example code, there follows a natural conclusion : if `N::A *a` is not a nice syntax when declaring a member variable of `A` itself (means, the natural syntax should rather be `A *a` to convey the same meaning), then it becomes pretty much obvious why injected-name are preferred over any other name. I mean it would be absurd if the syntax `A *a` in the class `A` declares a pointer variable of type other than `A`. Don't you think so?

Comment: Well, given that there are two types called `A` in the original question, one is the base class but in a different namespace and the other is not the base class but in the same namespace, I still think it's a very ambiguous situation. But I am grateful (+1) for what I learnt through the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

By qualifying `A` with `One::` you added the `A` from `namespace` one in scope, so the compiler will look there for it's name resolution.

Comment: But the object of type `A` declared inside the constructor has not been qualified with `One::`. It is interpreted as belonging to `namespace One`, although the declaration of `class B` itself is actually inside `namespace Two`.